# When extending a fabircjs class what is difference between _render() and render()?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm creating a custom fabric class. Looking though the fabric code I have noticed a public `render()` method as well as a private `_render()` method. While I understand that the underscore in the fabric code base denotes a private method I'm unsure what method I should override. What is the relationship between the public and private versions of `render()`? Why are there two different methods? When should I extend them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render()` is in Object class, which is used for drawing selection, transform of ctx, setting shadow and creating/re-drawing of the cache canvas.

While `_render()` uses to draw the specific object,like in Circle class, it draws an circle. So if you want to draw something as per your requirement, you need to override `_render()` of the specific class.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Circle.prototype._render = function(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  ctx.arc(
    0,
    0,
    this.radius,
    this.startAngle,
    this.endAngle, false);
  this._renderPaintInOrder(ctx);
  ctx.font="30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText('Hi!', 0, 0);
};

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 120,
  stroke: 'red',
  fill: ''
}));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```